# how to set encoding file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, busboy

I'm using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload), and when I upload a document that isn't txt, like a picture, pdf or doc document and I try to download it, the file is different from the one I've  uploaded( take a look to the picture ), I'm not sure if this is because a wrong encoding when uploading the file..

[image]
The left document is the original file.

The client:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
   scope: $scope,
   url: '/file/upload/',
   method:'POST',
   headers: {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'some token'
   }
});

$scope.upload = function(){
    uploader.queue.forEach(function(item){
        item.formData = [
        {'filename': 'friendlyName' },
        {'objectType': 'element' },
        {'elementId': 'someId'}
        ];
    });
    uploader.uploadAll();
};
```

The backend POST...

### In here the encoding variable within the file event of busboy is **'7bit'**..

```
exports.uploadDocument = function(req,res){
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    var doc = new DocumentModel();

    req.busboy.on('file',function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, contentType){
        doc.contentType = contentType;
        doc.encoding= encoding;
        doc.filename= filename;
        doc.content = '';
        doc.size = 0;
        file.on('data',function(data){
            doc.content += data;
            doc.size += data.length;
        });
    });

    //updating req.body with busboy parameters
    req.busboy.on('field',function(fieldname,val){
        req.body[fieldname] = val;
    });

    req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
        if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('filename')){
            doc.friendlyName = req.body.filename;
        }
        if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('objectType')){
            doc.reference.objectType = req.body.objectType;
        }
        if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('elementId')){
            doc.reference._id= req.body.elementId;
        }
        doc.save(function(err,savedFile){
            if(err){
                res.json(500,err.message);
            }else{
                res.json(200,doc);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Backend: GET...

```
exports.downloadDocument = function(req,res){
    var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.documentId);
        DocumentModel.findOneAsync({_id:id}).then(
        function(doc){
            console.log('doc', doc);
            if(doc!==undefined){
                DocumentModel.getFile(doc.fileInfoId).then(function(binaryData){
                    res.setHeader('x-timestamp', Date.now());
                    res.setHeader('x-sent',true);
                    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + doc.filename);
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type',doc.contentType);
                    res.send(binaryData);   
                }).error(function(e){
                    res.status(500).send(e.message);
                });
            }
            else{
                res.status(404).send('file not found.');
            }
        });
};
```

How can I set the correct encoding ? or is not an encoding issue?

This is the error I get when I try to see the downloaded file.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

PD:
Im using gridFS to store the document in mongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting binary data to UTF-8 implicitly by appending the data Buffers to `doc.content`, which is a string.

What you should probably do is make sure that the `content` field in your schema is set to `Buffer` and then you simply [concatenate file chunk Buffers](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) to keep the binary data intact. Example:

```
var bufs = [];
doc.size = 0;
file.on('data',function(data) {
  bufs[bufs.length] = data;
  doc.size += data.length;
}).on('end', function() {
  doc.content = Buffer.concat(bufs, doc.size);
});
```